# How to redirect to view from shared folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

```
HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Shared/views/Error.cshtml", true);
```

This is not working for me

And how to exclude the certain controllers and actions

Comment: Can you explain your problem a little bit more? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.110).aspx), method which you are trying to use require to arguments

```
public void Redirect(string url, bool endResponse)
```

and first argument is an `url` of page where user should be redirected, while you are passing view file path. In asp. mvc path to *cshtml file is not equal to url.

I suggest you to use `RedirectToRoute` method instead

```
RedirectToRoute(new RouteValueDictionary 
{
    controller = "Error", 
    action = "Index"
})
```

where your desired view is returned by `ErrorController.Index()` action.

Comment: With out calling a controller We cannot call a view Am I right??. Thank you @tutok

Comment: yes, you can not call *.cshtml directly, that file should be compiled firstly by  asp mvc pipeline.